# Minimize $\frac{|\sum_{k} a_k |}{\sum_{k} | a_k |} \frac{|\sum_{k} b_k |}{\sum_{k} | b_k |}$ for polynomial of order $2n$

Tags: polynomials, optimization

So I have a polynomial $p$ of order $2n$, which I want to factor into two polynomials $q$ and $r$, each of order $n$, while minimizing the expression
$$\frac{|\sum_{k} a_k |}{\sum_{k} | a_k |}  \frac{|\sum_{k} b_k |}{\sum_{k} | b_k |}$$

with $a_k$ and $b_k$ being the coefficients of $q$ and $r$ respectively. How would you approach solving something like this? I've tried solving it for the $n=1$ case, and that seems somewhat doable, just tedious.

Comment: Can you share what you did for the $n=1$ case? I'm curious about what you deem as "tedious", esp given that you don't have much choice about the factorization. Perhaps you're thinking of a slightly different question than how I interpreted it, and hence it would be helpful to clarify.

Comment: Would it mattter if you square the values instead of taking the _abs_ value? So why not $\displaystyle \frac{\left (\sum_k a_k \right )^2}{\sum_k (a_k)^2}\cdot\frac{\left (\sum_k b_k \right )^2}{\sum_k (b_k)^2}$? The advantage of the [LS method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares) is, by squaring it's derivable and that way you get min and/or max.